# d3: Smoothly animate a hand drawn line?

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

Please see [this pen](http://codepen.io/jonahx/pen/0c77b771cb0db378977c0236646f0ac8) for a working but janky version of what I want: a d3 animation that simulates, in real time, the path of a line being draw by a person.

I have two issues with my current implementation:

1. It's choppy.  You can see each piece of the path appearing as a chunk, rather than looking as if it was the path of a pen being moved across the screen.  One solution is to make each chunk smaller -- is there any other solution?
2. It's recursive.  Recursively calling draw with `setTimeout()` feels antithetical to the d3 spirit.  Is there a more declarative solution?  Perhaps one using `transition()`?

### Javascript

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                           .attr("width", "100%")
                           .attr("height", "100%");


var lineData = d3.range(5,800,15).map(function(x) {
  return {x: x, y: 10 + Math.floor(Math.random()*6)-3}
});

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                         .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                         .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("basis");

function draw(points) {

  var lineGraph = svg.append("path")                            
                     .attr("stroke", "blue")
                     .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                     .attr("fill", "none")
                     .attr("d", lineFunction(points));
  
  if (points.length < lineData.length)
    setTimeout(function(){
      draw(lineData.slice(0,points.length+1));
    }, 50);
}

draw([]);
```

Comment: Here's a method that will make it really look hand-drawn.. https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/d9995b8f12e23063f17c   Demo:http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/upjDy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[See this simple (and neat) trick](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592) for gradually animating the drawing of a path, using `stroke-dasharray`. Here's [your code, modified](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lpbyh).

```
var lineGraph = svg
  .append("path")
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
  .transition()
  .duration(5000)
  .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)

function tweenDash() {
  var l = this.getTotalLength(),
      i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
  return function(t) { return i(t); };
}
```

Comment: Wonderful solution! Thanks.